# How do I restore missing Launcher and Panel in Unity?

Tags: login, launcher, panel

I had this Ubuntu infinite login loop problem, and after searching the forum, I did these steps.

```
Ctrl + Alt + F6

ls -lah
```

I found `-rw------- 1 root root 20 Dec .Xauthority`

So I did `chown username:username .Xauthority` as mentioned by someone in the forums.

After this I tried to login from my user, and it worked, but now I'm facing a new problem, that is, the Launcher and Panel are missing. 
Did I do anything wrong ?

Further I did

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

But it gave an error

```
error: cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Please post an answer if you have solved it, instead of editing the question.

Comment: I've just discovered that I can answer my own question ! so, did as you suggested. Hope it would be helpful for others too facing similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solved this problem, though I'm not sure which one below solved the problem, since I tried both steps successively.

Try 1:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
export DISPLAY=:0
ccsm
```

Try 2:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz
unity --reset-icons &disown
```

To get back to the login screen

```
service lightdm restart
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried every solution to this on the whole Internet and this fixed it for me:

`unity --reset-icons &disown`

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest that you did something wrong. I encountered the same issue with unity through  installing updates.

it seems the fix is to run

`dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`

which resets the compiz profiles and plugins associated with unity.

after the command you could reboot or simply restart lightdm (`sudo service lightdm restart`)and log back in.

**Second Solution**

It may be worth adding `export DISPLAY=:0` to the command which would make my first suggestion change to `export DISPLAY=:0 && dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`

Alternatively you could log in then swap to a tty (crtl+alt+F1)and send a terminal to the desktop, which can be achieved by `export DISPLAY=:0 && gnome-terminal` then hitting ctrl+alt+f7 to get back to the GUI and then try executing  `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` from the terminal that should be on your unity-less desktop.

sorry if this is confusing , but im not sure how else to get around your error

Comment: I tried as you said, but as I typed the first command, it throws an error
error: cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY

Comment: I'm not sure how much more help i can be , but would you mind adding the error to your question ? somebody else may know what to do

Comment: ive added a second solution , sorry again if its confusing